# Xamarin Memory Limitation or?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Can anyone tell me if they have run into any "memory" limitations with Xamarin Forms App for Android?

I recently decided to give Xamarin another go... A few years back I ran into far too many hurdles and went a different route. I hoped things had changed.

I have an empty Xamarin Forms App for Android ONLY at this point (no OSX or UWP support). I created and updated the initial app (4.3 Xamarin Forms). I modified the mainpage.xaml and the mainpage.xaml.cs. Simple 3 row grid... 2 columns... first row, small header image centered columnspan="2"... Second row is also centered, with a CollectionView to "horizontally" scroll some simple small icon/images... Third row of gird is for detail (not yet implemented). So, with this, you can see the application is still quite small and has no real magic going on... Here is the delimma...

I have 8 c# Objects that are a c# Class... I began building the application using a simplified version of the class... Name, and ImageName only for the purpose of testing the 4.3 CollectionView for a navigation UI... After I had the functionality I wanted and it was running and tested for deployment to device, Everything seemed fine... So, I continued and built out the full class objects (13 fields, all strings no real data entered, just empty quotes for value = "". The only fields I have filled in are the original Name and ImageName is code read only... Running the App in the emulator, it now fails on load... and the emulator asks if I would like to close or try and reload...

It seems that my display class, when the class has more than the first few fields filled in causes some sort of overload:

var displaylist = new List<"DisplayClass"> ();

var dc = New DisplayClass({Name = "This Icon"})... add all 8 and things are working...

var dc = new DisplayClass({Name="This Icon", State="MA", Style="", Definition="", ... all others empty string});
   --- add all 8 classes with names only and all empty fields... fails to load app...

```
public class DisplayClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Style { get; set; }
    public string Definition { get; set; }
    public string Days { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string Imageurl { get; set; }
    public string Dataurl { get; set; }
    public string Retrievalurl { get; set; }
    public string LastRetrievalDate { get; set; }
    public string LastInfoData { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string ImageName 
    {
        get { return Name.Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToLower(); } 
    }
}
```

I updated the emulator to use 4GB instead of 1GB, but that had no effect. There are no code errors that I can tell, if I remark out the full object classes and implement the stripped out version it works without error... I do not get an error, only a App failed to start dialog from Android...

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Have you tried on a real device?  Which emulator image are you using?  Google's Android emulators are historically pretty bad, although they have improved recently.  I've written very complex Forms apps for iOS and Android without problems, as have thousands of other people.

Comment: Jason... thanks for the quick response... Of course this would have had to have been my own mistake... I was having trouble with MS documentation on Xamarin... I also had 3 days of back and forth on horizontal UI elements, only to find that 4.3 had exactly what I needed... So, I was quick on the post... I had a bad attitude about Xamarin and that didn't help... At any rate... thanks for your quick response...

Answer (score 0):

My bad... I had an un-instantiated datetime in my class... oops... sorry folks!